# Crash when using WebView on Ubuntu Touch Xenial

Tags: qt, qml, nexus-5, ubuntu-touch

I am trying to add a webview to a ubports app based off the clickable `ut-app-cmake-template`. This gave me a simple hello world app.

I added a webview into my layout:

```
WebView {                                                                                                                                                                                              
    id: webView                                                                                                                                                                                        
    url: "https://www.google.com"                                                                  

    anchors {                                                                                                                                                                                          
        left: parent.left                                                                                                                                                                              
        right: parent.right                                                                                                                                                                            
        bottom: parent.bottom                                                                                                                                                                          
        top: loginPage.header.bottom                                                                                                                                                                   
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                  

    incognito: true                                                                                                                                                                                    
    preferences.localStorageEnabled: true                                                                                                                                                              
    preferences.allowFileAccessFromFileUrls: true                                                                                                                                                      
    preferences.allowUniversalAccessFromFileUrls: true                                                                                                                                                 
    preferences.appCacheEnabled: true                                                                                                                                                                  
    preferences.javascriptCanAccessClipboard: true                                                                                                                                                     
}
```

I then ran this on the phone using `clickable --xenial` and it crashes straight away with the error (from `clickable logs`):

```
Loading module: 'libubuntu_application_api_touch_mirclient.so.3.0.0'
LaunchProcess: failed to execvp:
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/oxide-qt/chrome-sandbox
[0919/232725:FATAL:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(182)] Check failed: ReceiveFixedMessage(fds[0], kZygoteBootMessage, sizeof(kZygoteBootMessage), &boot_pid).
#0 0x0000ab9e131a <unknown>
#1 0x0000ab9f043a <unknown>
#2 0x0000ab2814aa <unknown>
#3 0x0000ab280a50 <unknown>
#4 0x0000ab280de0 <unknown>
#5 0x0000ab091fa6 <unknown>
#6 0x0000ab095a82 <unknown>
#7 0x0000ac6aea88 <unknown>
#8 0x0000aafa6a0c <unknown>
#9 0x0000ae0b7c86 oxide::qquick::EnsureChromiumStarted()
#10 0x0000ae0abfbc OxideQQuickWebView::OxideQQuickWebView()
#11 0x0000ae11eee6 QQmlPrivate::QQmlElement<>::QQmlElement()
#12 0x0000ae11ef2e QQmlPrivate::createInto<>()
```

Looking into this a bit it seemed like it was to do with apparmor permissons, so I added a bunch of permissons to the apparmor file based of a project I was using as a template.

```
{                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    "policy_groups": [                                                                                                                                                                                         
        "networking",                                                                                                                                                                                          
        "connectivity",                                                                                                                                                                                        
        "content_exchange",                                                                                                                                                                                    
        "content_exchange_source",                                                                                                                                                                             
        "usermetrics",                                                                                                                                                                                         
        "webview",                                                                                                                                                                                             
        "keep-display-on",                                                                                                                                                                                     
        "audio",                                                                                                                                                                                               
        "video",                                                                                                                                                                                               
        "debug"                                                                                                                                                                                                
    ],                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    "policy_version": 1.3                                                                                                                                                                                      
}
```

However this didn't seem to fix the issue.

I'm probably just missing something simple in a config somewhere. Does anyone know what I need to add or change to stop this crash on app startup?

Device: LGE Nexus 5, OS: Ubuntu 16.04 (2018-W35)